# how can I select a particular Div after getting result back using jquery and $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to select a particular Div after calling a php using $.ajax:
my PHP file produce a HTML like following :

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="res_num">123</div>
</body></html>
```

and in another file I can load the above html and attach it to my current HTML but I want to get the "123" not the whole HTML for this matter I've written something like :

```
var param = "ID=1";
    $.ajax({    
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "latest.php",
                    data: param,  //with the page number as a parameter
                    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned

                    success: function(msg){

                        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)    //if no errors
                        {

                            $('#result').html(msg);    
                            //below line works !!!
                            var handle = $(msg).html(); //filter("div.num_result").html();
                            /following line doens't help me even changing it with .find doesn't help me
                            var myDiv = $(handle).filter("div.res_num"); 
                            alert(handle.html());

                        }
                        }
```

How can I get only a portion of a html using jquery selector and ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that provides this functionality, namely:

```
// read the .load documentation for the "strange" URL
$("#result").load("latest.php #res_num", param);
```

However, `.load` constrains you heavily on *what you can do* with the filtered HTML: it places it inside an existing element and that's that. If that's too restrictive then you will have to modify what your code on the server side returns (although from your example it looks like it would work in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(msg).contents().find("#res_num");
```

should work

Comment: nope! handle = $(msg).contents().find("#num_result");
                            alert(handle.text());

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var myDiv = $(handle).filter("div.res_num");
```

to

```
var myDiv = $(handle).filter("#res_num");
```

Comment: doesn't make any difference .still get null or empty

Comment: Could you try `$('#result').find('#res_num');`?